# View multi-line (view mode) into Edit Form

Tags: multiline-text-field

I am trying to insert a multi-line data field (read only) into an edit form. Reason: I want the user to be able to see the previous notes, but not add new ones.

So, I opened the view form, and copied the following field out of it and put it into my edit form, BUT, it only shows the last entry appended to the notes... what am I missing? In the View Form it shows each entry AND the user who made the entry along with the date/time stamp.

```
 <tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Notes</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>

    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Notes" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is this an append only field?

Comment: Instead use Javascript to make it read only on edit form.

Comment: @W.Scott my intent was to duplicate the field. One field just to view the current notes, and a duplicate field to add new notes. To get there, I created an edit form, and inserted the notes field from the view form.